# how to make a policy to tag CreatedBy: AccountID?

Tags: azure, policy

i am trying to make a policy that tag each resource we create in our organization with the AccountID value.

i have two tags to force:

1. CreatedDate
2. CreatedBy

The "CreatedBy" tag name i cant find any idea how to insert the "AccountID" who created this resource in the tag value.
I saw when i create a kubernetes service that his resources have this TagName CreatedBy that pointing to the kubernetes .. which means that kind of solution already exist i guess.

my policy looks like this :

```
 {
   "mode": "All",
   "policyRule": {
     "if": {
       "allOf": [
         {
           "field": "tags['CreatedOnDate']",
           "exists": "false"
         },
         {
           "field": "tags['CreatedBy']",
           "exists": "false"
         }
       ]
     },
     "then": {
       "effect": "append",
       "details": [
         {
           "field": "tags['CreatedOnDate']",
           "value": "[utcNow()]"
         },
         {
              
           "field": "tags['CreatedBy']",
           "value": [????]
         }
       ]
     }
   },
   "parameters": {}
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example to [automatically tag resources with creator's name](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/tagging-azure-resources-with-a-creator/ba-p/1479819).

Answer (score 2):

here is my solution ...
i am earching for all resources with tag name = "created_By" = "None" (i taged all my resources like this)
than i get the caller id from the az-log if available, after i run this one time i make a schdule runbook to run everyday and tag the created resources of the last day.(of course dont forget to modify the date to- `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)`

```powershell
$resourceWithTag = Get-AzResource -Tag @{ created_By = "None" }



# Tag each resource with tag name 'created_By = None' with his CallerID'
foreach ($resource in $resourceWithTag) {
    $users = Get-AzLog -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) -EndTime (Get-Date)| Select-Object Caller | Where-Object { $_.Caller } | Sort-Object -Property Caller -Unique | Sort-Object -Property Caller -Descending
    if ((!$users) -or ($users.Caller -eq $null)) {
        Write-Output "no logs"
    }
    else {
    Update-AzTag -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId -Tag @{ created_By = $users[0]} -Operation Merge
   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here an slightly different version of @Yahav script.

I set the Tag `vf-creator` via Azure policy to `ToBeSetFromLog`
The script run in a Azure Automation Account to look for such
(I have many sub to need to loop thru the subscriptions)

Managed identity need Tag rights (Tag Contribute) and read on the Activity log (Read role)

The script search for the word `create` in the event log `OperationName` not bullet proof but get the job done it seems.

here the PS code:

```powershell
##Tilo Runbook to set Tags based on event log

##set Variables
$myTagName = "vf-creator"

#start
Write-Output "$(Get-Date -format o) :: Start-Script"
## Connect: 
# Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
# Connect to Azure with system-assigned managed identity
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
# Set and store context
$AzureContextFull = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription

##:List all subs which are enabled
$AllSubs = Get-AzSubscription
$AllSubID = $AllSubs.SubscriptionId
Write-Output "$(Get-Date -format o) :: List of Subscription below"
$AllSubs | ft -auto

##now loop all subs
Foreach ($SubID in $AllSubID) {
Set-AzContext -Subscription $SubID | ft -auto
Write-Output "$(Get-Date -format o) Now work on Sub: $SubID"

##tag will be set via policy to "ToBeSetFromLog"; so the resource search is fast. 
$resourceToBeTagged = Get-AzResource -Tag @{ $myTagName = "ToBeSetFromLog" }

##Loop each resource which need to be tagged
foreach ($resource in $resourceToBeTagged) {
##read logs
Write-Output "$(Get-Date -format o) Read Event Log for Res: $($resource.name) ID: $($resource.ResourceId)"
$eventlogs = Get-AzLog -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-16) -EndTime (Get-Date) -Status 'Succeeded' -MaxRecord 5000 |
    Where-Object {$_.Caller -ne $null} |
    Where-Object {$_.OperationName -like "*create*"} |
    Sort-Object EventTimestamp |
    Select-Object -First 1
    
  if ($eventlogs.Caller -eq $null){  
     $User = "ToBeSetManual"
     Write-Output "$(Get-Date -format o) Couldn't read log; Set $myTagName to $User on Res: $($resource.name)"
     }  
 else {  
     $User = $eventlogs.Caller
     Write-Output "$(Get-Date -format o) Set $myTagName to $User on Res: $($resource.name)"
    }  
#Now set tag:
Update-AzTag -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId -Tag @{ $myTagName = $User} -Operation Merge
}


}

Write-Output "$(Get-Date -format o) :: Done Script"
```